# How do I download App Store?

Tags: slideshow

I have a school iPad but the main iPad have cracks and the teacher doesn’t like the App Store  and I can’t get it and also I can only get school games

Comment: If your iPad is under the school's control, then you have to ask the school if they would allow anything outside their current limitations. We cannot help with that, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Your school will be managing their Ipads with an MDM (Mobile Device Management) solution, like Mosyle or JAMF.

Apple have introduced functionality to iOS that allows MDMs to disable access to the App Store (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mdm/mdm0f7dd3d8/web)

As a result you will not be able to install any game apps and instead will be limited to browser-based games (https://miniclip.com/games/en/ etc)